# How do you get a numerical value from a UIDatepicker?

Tags: iphone, c++, xcode, uidatepicker

i am developing an app that involves getting a value from a datepicker and subtracting it from the date displayed on the actual iphone. how will i do this? i have looked everywhere for an answer!

thanks Rafee

Comment: Have a look through some of the `NSDate` documentation :) http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: What do you mean by "getting a value from a datepicker and subtracting it from the date displayed on the actual iphone"?

Answer (score 1):

You should implement `datePickerValueChanged` as the selector, and implement like this.

```
- (void)datePickerValueChanged:(UIDatePicker*) date_Picker{


NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
df.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
NSString *dateFromPicker = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[df stringFromDate:date_Picker.date]];

    // calculating time difference now

    NSDate *timeRightNow = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval diff = [timeRightNow timeIntervalSinceDate:date_Picker.date];

    // The difference should always be in seconds. Here, 3628800 represents 6 weeks.

    if (diff > 3628800){

      // Do something if the entered date is six weeks from the iPhone date.

   }


 }
```